# How can I translate a RAISE EXCEPTION from Postgres to Oracle?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, exception

can you please suggest me which is the best way to translate the following EXCEPTION from Postgres to Oracle?

```
            IF ls_P2_RULE_SCOPE is null THEN 
            
                RAISE EXCEPTION 'Rule % : Missing Rule Scope', ls_P2_RULE
                USING HINT = 'Please check Rule Definition';
            
            END IF;
```

Thank you!

I've tried with some suggestions I've found on internet but they didn't seem to suit my case

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```sql
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(
  -20000,
  'Rule ' || ls_P2_RULE || ' : Missing Rule Scope.'
  || ' Please check Rule Definition'
);
```

For example:

```sql
DECLARE
  ls_P2_RULE VARCHAR2(20) := 'Something';
BEGIN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(
    -20000,
    'Rule ' || ls_P2_RULE || ' : Missing Rule Scope.'
    || ' Please check Rule Definition'
  );
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ORA-20000: Rule Something : Missing Rule Scope. Please check Rule Definition
> ORA-06512: at line 4
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TVlW9eb1)